# in MSSQL Server 2005 Dev Edition, I faced index corruption

Tags: sql-server-2005, corruption

When running stored procedures in MSSQL Server, I found it failed and the DBMS (MSSQL Server 2005 Dev Edition) notified that some indexes are corrupted.

### Please advice me, here below is DBCC logs:

```
DBCC results for 'itopup_dev'.  
Service Broker Msg 9675, State 1: Message Types analyzed: 14.  
Service Broker Msg 9676, State 1: Service Contracts analyzed: 6.  
Service Broker Msg 9667, State 1: Services analyzed: 3.  
Service Broker Msg 9668, State 1: Service Queues analyzed: 3.  
Service Broker Msg 9669, State 1: Conversation Endpoints analyzed: 0.  
Service Broker Msg 9674, State 1: Conversation Groups analyzed: 0.  
Service Broker Msg 9670, State 1: Remote Service Bindings analyzed: 0.  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsetcolumns'.  
There are 1148 rows in 14 pages for object "sys.sysrowsetcolumns".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsets'.  
There are 187 rows in 2 pages for object "sys.sysrowsets".  
DBCC results for 'sysallocunits'.  
There are 209 rows in 3 pages for object "sysallocunits".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfiles1'.  
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysfiles1".  
DBCC results for 'sys.syshobtcolumns'.  
There are 1148 rows in 14 pages for object "sys.syshobtcolumns".  
DBCC results for 'sys.syshobts'.  
There are 187 rows in 2 pages for object "sys.syshobts".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysftinds'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysftinds".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysserefs'.  
There are 209 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysserefs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysowners'.  
There are 15 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysowners".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysprivs'.  
There are 135 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysprivs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysschobjs'.  
There are 817 rows in 21 pages for object "sys.sysschobjs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.syscolpars'.  
There are 2536 rows in 71 pages for object "sys.syscolpars".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysnsobjs'.  
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysnsobjs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.syscerts'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscerts".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxprops'.  
There are 12 rows in 4 pages for object "sys.sysxprops".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysscalartypes'.  
There are 27 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysscalartypes".  
DBCC results for 'sys.systypedsubobjs'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.systypedsubobjs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysidxstats'.  
There are 466 rows in 15 pages for object "sys.sysidxstats".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysiscols'.  
There are 616 rows in 6 pages for object "sys.sysiscols".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbinobjs'.  
There are 23 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysbinobjs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysobjvalues'.  
There are 1001 rows in 376 pages for object "sys.sysobjvalues".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysclsobjs'.  
There are 14 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysclsobjs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsetrefs'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysrowsetrefs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysremsvcbinds'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysremsvcbinds".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmitqueue'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxmitqueue".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrts'.  
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysrts".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysconvgroup'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysconvgroup".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdesend'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdesend".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdercv'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdercv".  
DBCC results for 'sys.syssingleobjrefs'.  
There are 317 rows in 2 pages for object "sys.syssingleobjrefs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysmultiobjrefs'.  
There are 3607 rows in 37 pages for object "sys.sysmultiobjrefs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbfiles'.  
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysdbfiles".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysguidrefs'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysguidrefs".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysqnames'.  
There are 91 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysqnames".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmlcomponent'.  
There are 93 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysxmlcomponent".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmlfacet'.  
There are 97 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysxmlfacet".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmlplacement'.  
There are 17 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysxmlplacement".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysobjkeycrypts'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysobjkeycrypts".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysasymkeys'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysasymkeys".  
DBCC results for 'sys.syssqlguides'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syssqlguides".  
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbinsubobjs'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysbinsubobjs".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_BONUS_TEMPLATES'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_BONUS_TEMPLATES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ROLE_PAGE_GROUP'.  
There are 18 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_ROLE_PAGE_GROUP".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_BONUS_LEVELS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_BONUS_LEVELS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SUPERADMIN'.  
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SUPERADMIN".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ADMIN_ROLES'.  
There are 11 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_ADMIN_ROLES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ADMIN_USER_ROLE'.  
There are 42 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_ADMIN_USER_ROLE".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_BONUS_CALCULATION_HISTORIES'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_BONUS_CALCULATION_HISTORIES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_MOBILES'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_MOBILES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ARCHIVE_EXPORTED_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 16030918 rows in 35344 pages for object "TBL_ARCHIVE_EXPORTED_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ARCHIVE_LOGS'.  
There are 280 rows in 2 pages for object "TBL_ARCHIVE_LOGS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ADMIN_USERS'.  
There are 29 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_ADMIN_USERS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYSTEM_ALERT_GROUPS'.  
There are 4 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SYSTEM_ALERT_GROUPS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_EXPORTED_TRANSACTIONS'.  
There are 7848 rows in 89 pages for object "TBL_EXPORTED_TRANSACTIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYSTEM_ALERTS'.  
There are 968 rows in 9 pages for object "TBL_SYSTEM_ALERTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYSTEM_ALERT_GROUP_MEMBERS'.  
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SYSTEM_ALERT_GROUP_MEMBERS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ESTIMATED_TIME'.  
There are 11 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_ESTIMATED_TIME".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYSTEM_ALERT_MEMBERS'.  
There are 0 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SYSTEM_ALERT_MEMBERS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_COMMISSIONS'.  
There are 10031 rows in 106 pages for object "TBL_COMMISSIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_CATEGORIES'.  
There are 3 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_CATEGORIES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SERVICE_PROVIDERS'.  
There are 11 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SERVICE_PROVIDERS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_CATEGORY_SERVICE_PROVIDER'.  
There are 11 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_CATEGORY_SERVICE_PROVIDER".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_PRODUCTS'.  
There are 73 rows in 6 pages for object "TBL_PRODUCTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_KEYS'.  
There are 291 rows in 30 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_KEYS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_POS_UNLOCK_KEYS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_POS_UNLOCK_KEYS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_POS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_POS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_IMPORT_BATCHES'.  
There are 3285 rows in 84 pages for object "TBL_IMPORT_BATCHES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_IMPORT_KEYS'.  
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_IMPORT_KEYS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_PRODUCT_COMMISSION_TEMPLATES'.  
There are 634 rows in 4 pages for object "TBL_PRODUCT_COMMISSION_TEMPLATES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_POS_SETTLE_TRANSACTIONS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_POS_SETTLE_TRANSACTIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_CHANGE_KEY_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 0 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_CHANGE_KEY_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_POS_RETURN_TRANSACTIONS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_POS_RETURN_TRANSACTIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_POS_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_POS_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_POS_MENUS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_POS_MENUS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_COMMISSION_TEMPLATES'.  
There are 23 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_COMMISSION_TEMPLATES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_DOWNLOAD_TRANSACTIONS'.  
There are 170820 rows in 1789 pages for object "TBL_DOWNLOAD_TRANSACTIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_IMPORT_TEMP_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 0 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_IMPORT_TEMP_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_REGIONS'.  
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_REGIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 9723677 rows in 126611 pages for object "TBL_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'sysdiagrams'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sysdiagrams".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYNCHRONIZE_TRANSACTIONS'.  
There are 9302 rows in 53 pages for object "TBL_SYNCHRONIZE_TRANSACTIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SALEMEN'.  
There are 32 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SALEMEN".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_RESERVATION_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 131431 rows in 1629 pages for object "TBL_RESERVATION_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYNCHRONIZE_TRANSACTION_ITEMS'.  
There are 5345 rows in 16 pages for object "TBL_SYNCHRONIZE_TRANSACTION_ITEMS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ACCOUNTS'.  
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_ACCOUNTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SYNCHRONIZE_TRANSACTION_SOFTPIN'.  
There are 821988 rows in 2744 pages for object "TBL_SYNCHRONIZE_TRANSACTION_SOFTPIN".  
***DBCC results for 'TBL_EXPORTED_SOFTPINS'.  
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
Object ID 1716917188, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594046119936, alloc unit ID   72057594050838528 (type In-row data): Page (1:677314) could not be processed.  See other   errors for details.  
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 7, Line 1  
Table error: Object ID 1716917188, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594046119936, alloc unit   ID 72057594050838528 (type In-row data), page (1:677314). Test (m_freeData >= PAGEHEADSIZE   && m_freeData <= (UINT)PAGESIZE - m_slotCnt * sizeof (Slot)) failed. Values  are 15428 and 7240.  
There are 2267937 rows in 6133 pages for object "TBL_EXPORTED_SOFTPINS".  
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 2 consistency errors in table 'TBL_EXPORTED_SOFTPINS'   (object ID 1716917188).***
DBCC results for 'TBL_DOWNLOAD_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 7029404 rows in 17999 pages for object "TBL_DOWNLOAD_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_BALANCE_CREDIT_PAID'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_BALANCE_CREDIT_PAID".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ARCHIVE_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 44015040 rows in 683692 pages for object "TBL_ARCHIVE_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE_LOGS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE_LOGS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_BLOCK_BATCHES'.  
There are 23 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_BLOCK_BATCHES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_BLOCK_BATCH_SOFTPIN'.  
There are 396 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_BLOCK_BATCH_SOFTPIN".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANTS'.  
There are 290 rows in 22 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_DOWNLOAD_TRANSACTION_ITEMS'.  
There are 189296 rows in 1241 pages for object "TBL_DOWNLOAD_TRANSACTION_ITEMS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_BLOCK_BATCH_CONDITIONS'.  
There are 23 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_BLOCK_BATCH_CONDITIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SP_ADVERTISEMENTS'.  
There are 6 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SP_ADVERTISEMENTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SERVER_KEYS'.  
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SERVER_KEYS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ARCHIVE_DOWNLOAD_SOFTPINS'.  
There are 27984122 rows in 60773 pages for object "TBL_ARCHIVE_DOWNLOAD_SOFTPINS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE_REQUESTS'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE_REQUESTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_TERMINALS'.  
There are 633 rows in 4 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_TERMINALS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_SP_PREFIXES'.  
There are 6 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_SP_PREFIXES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_DIRECT_TOPUP_TRANSACTIONS'.  
There are 43 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_DIRECT_TOPUP_TRANSACTIONS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_BALANCE_REQUESTS'.  
There are 19367 rows in 171 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_BALANCE_REQUESTS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ACTION_LOGS'.  
There are 133714 rows in 1569 pages for object "TBL_ACTION_LOGS".  
DBCC results for 'sys.queue_messages_1977058079'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.queue_messages_1977058079".  
DBCC results for 'sys.queue_messages_2009058193'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.queue_messages_2009058193".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_CODES'.  
There are 98 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_CODES".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_BALANCE_LOGS'.  
There are 183498 rows in 3178 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_BALANCE_LOGS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_MERCHANT_CHANNEL_TEMPLATE'.  
There are 397 rows in 2 pages for object "TBL_MERCHANT_CHANNEL_TEMPLATE".  
DBCC results for 'sys.queue_messages_2041058307'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.queue_messages_2041058307".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_VNPTEPAY'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_VNPTEPAY".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_PAGE_GROUPS'.  
There are 10 rows in 1 pages for object "TBL_PAGE_GROUPS".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_PAGE_GROUP_PAGE'.  
There are 513 rows in 2 pages for object "TBL_PAGE_GROUP_PAGE".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_ACCOUNT_CHANNEL_TEMPLATE'.  
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "TBL_ACCOUNT_CHANNEL_TEMPLATE".  
DBCC results for 'TBL_PAGES'.  
There are 148 rows in 3 pages for object "TBL_PAGES".  
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 2 consistency errors in database 'itopup_dev'.  
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB   (itopup_dev).  
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Happens.

- Patch up your Server. Lastest service pack AND CUMULATIVE UPDATE.
- Recreate the indices.

If I remember correctly there is an old bug that could corrupt indices that was long long ago fixed.... but... the corrupted indices need recreation.

But you have not ONLY corrupted indices - you seem to also have bad pages. DBCC says it needs a repair level allowing data loss, and I think I see something about bad data in the middle...

> Test (m_freeData >= PAGEHEADSIZE &&
>   m_freeData <= (UINT)PAGESIZE -
>   m_slotCnt * sizeof (Slot)) failed.
>   Values are 15428 and 7240. There are
>   2267937 rows in 6133 pages for object
>   "TBL_EXPORTED_SOFTPINS".

Export data, scrub it, reimport it. Fire admin for not running that regularly. Alternatively... apply latest backup, roll forward transaction logs. Promote admin for catching this and doing his job.

Comment: I found that my MSSQL Server is shutdown abnormally by Windows Server 2003 R2 automatic update. 
You should turn it off to avoid this corruption.